# Magento 2 - Redirects search if only one result

Tags: php, magento, redirect, magento2

I'm trying to custom the default Magento 2 search engine. I would like to automatically redirects to the product page when search returns only one result.
I tried to override the Result/Index controller but nothings worked.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

This is a native feature of ElasticSuite : https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite

Maybe should you give a try at the extension.

Disclosure : I am the lead developper of ElasticSuite

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the configuration, no need to devellop anything additionnal. Here is a link to a good resource : https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-manage-search-term-in-magento-2/

If you really need to redirect programmatically, I advise you to use dependency injection more than override.

Comment: Thanks for your help, sadly the configuration needs to be written for every product and it could be a little time consuming. I'm looking to another solution, override or dependency injection.

Comment: On M2, you can use quite often DI for that kind of behavior it is easier to implement and closer to the coding standards than overriding.